# Render an html element inside bootstrap model with javascript tag

Tags: html, css

I need to render a HTML element inside a Bootstrap modal using a script tag, the problem is that the button renders outside the modal.

Im using this JS code:

```
var btn = '<button>BUTTON</button>';
div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = btn;
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

I call the JS with script tag :

```
<script src="button.js" ></script>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffarinas/tprngm0c/1/)

Comment: If you don't want it as a direct child of the `document.body`, why are you doing `document.body.appendChild(div);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the append the button to the right parent element.

```
const btn = '<button>BUTTON</button>';
const body = document.querySelector('.modal-body')
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = btn;
body.appendChild(div);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pydqz52x/